# How to use the command update-alternatives --config

Tags: java, linux, debian, kali-linux

sorry if my English bad, I have a problem, every time I want to run burpsuite or subgraph vega, I must run this code

```
update-alternatives --config java 

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

when I want to run burpsuite, I must to choose 0. when I want to run subgraph vega, I must to choose 2 then the application can run. it's complicated so can you help me, when I run burpsuite,

```
update-alternative --config java
```

will automatic select 0,  when I run subgraph vega, will automatic select 2 and can I run both this application at same time?

Comment: Can you not run the application with the full paths to the java executables? so /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java for burpsuite and usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java for subgraph

Comment: yes working for this /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar /bin/burpsuite , but no for this /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar /bin/vega